# Jquery Validation: CSS (valid or error) does not initally show up IF I use the remote method

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the remote method in the JQuery Validation plugin, to check if an email exists, which works fine. However, the css (.valid or .error) does not initially display after submit or re-submit.

So, if I submit the form with an unused email, the remote check returns true, but the css that should be applied to the email field (border size, style, color) is not applied until I click submit again. After clicking on the submit the second time the css takes effect.

If I submit the form with a used email, the remote check returns false, and the css does show correctly (border color, style, size). When changing the email, another check is performed, but the css does not change (to valid) until I re-submit again.

If I remove the remote method and add X fields with different requirements, the CSS is displayed fine for both .valid and .error classes. It's something to do with the remote method that screws it up somehow.

Would anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this issue ? (code below) --

CSS-

> .lmap_default input.error {
>          border:1px solid red;
>      }
>
> .lmap_default input.valid {
>          border: 1px solid #3C8D2F;
>      }

HTML & JQuery-

```
<div id="formdiv">
<form id="Register" action="" method="post" class="lmap_default">
    <h1>Register
        <span>Please fill your email and password to register.</span>
    </h1>
    <label for="email">
        <span>Your Email :</span>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="A Valid Email Address" />
    </label>
    <label for="password">
        <span>Your Password :</span>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter a password" />
    </label>
    <label for="v_password">
        <span>Confirm Password:</span>
        <input type="password" name="v_password" placeholder="Confirm The Password Above" />
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>&nbsp;</span>
        <input type="hidden" name="form" value="Register" />
        <input type="submit" value="Register" id="submit_register" />
    </label>
</form>
```

```
$(function() {
    $.validator.addMethod("regx", function(value, element, regexpr) {
        return regexpr.test(value);
    }, "<strong><p>* Incorrect Format");
    $('#Register').validate({
        onkeyup: false,
        onfocusout: false,
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                remote: {
                    async: false,
                    url: 'processing/form_process.php',
                    type: 'post'
                }
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                regx: /^(?=(?:.*?[A-Za-z]){4})(?=(?:.*?[0-9]){2})[A-Za-z0-9!@#$',\\.-_ ]+$/,
                minlength: 6,
                maxlength: 30
            },
            v_password: {
                required: true,
                equalTo: "#password"
            }
        },
        messages: {
            email: {
                required: "Please enter an email",
                email: "Please enter a valid email address",
                remote: jQuery.validator.format("<strong>* Email ({0}) is already in use</strong>")
            },
            password: {
                required: "Please enter a password",
                minlength: jQuery.validator.format("Enter at least {0} characters")
            },
            v_password: {
                required: "Please re-enter your password",
                equalTo: "The password entered is not the same"
            }
        },

        submitHandler: function(form) {
                $.post('processing/form_process.php',
                    $('#Register').serialize(),
                    function(data){
                        $('#formdiv').html(data);
                    });
        }
    });
});
```

PHP (check if email is already used) -

```
            if(isset($_POST['email']) && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $connection->query('SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = :email');
            $connection->bind(':email', $email);
            $row_count = $connection->resultset();
            if (count($row_count) == 0) {
                echo json_encode(true);
            } else {
                echo json_encode(false);
            }
        }
```

Comment: `async: false` means that everything else is going to have to wait for that `remote` request to finish.  Try removing it.

Comment: @Sparky : After removing async, on submitting an incorrect email  (using the remote method) the field returns using the .valid class and then once the remote call is finished returns correctly using the .error class without resubmitting, BUT the password fields return with the .valid class (initially the error class was applied before the remote call) even though they are incorrect. After clicking on submit again (without changing their values), they now show with the correct .error class applied.

Comment: With both `onkeyup` and `onfocusout` set to `false`, the only way left to trigger validation is by the click of the `submit` button.  How else could it know the user is done typing into the field?

Comment: @Sparky: On submit validation would occur -- that's fine. However, the issue is that when the submit button is clicked AFTER the user changed the email to something valid (previously returned false), the error class is still applied to the email field, even though it is now valid.  
 The submit button needs to be clicked an additional time, for the correct class (valid) to be applied to the email field.

Comment: @Sparky: I'm not expecting validation to occur before submit. I'm saying that AFTER submit (This would be the second submit, after the user changed their email to something valid), the .error class is STILL applied to the email field (not the valid class). The error message for email however is not there anymore (after submit) to indicate that there are no errors for this field.

Comment: No idea what you're talking about, but your submit button is your only trigger to test the form, so the form is going to remain in whatever state until the form is corrected and the button is clicked again.  Can you assemble a jSFiddle demo?

Comment: @Sparky: The css issues ONLY appear when using the remote method in the jquery validation plugin. I don't think I can replicate it with jsfiddle (can't remote using php), but I uploaded the files (same content as above) to a free host to test and it'll show the same issue: http://sm00nie.byethost22.com/.

Comment: @Sparky : To replicate the error, enter duplicate email -> test@test.com, password -> test1, confirm password -> test2 (a valid password will be a minimum of 2 numbers and 4 letters). After clicking on submit, you'll see that only the email field has the error css, while the password fields do not. If you make no changes and click on submit again, all the invalid fields have error css (as it correctly should have been displayed when submit was initially clicked).

Comment: Just an FYI, in case this is a bug of some sort, jQuery Validate is only tested up through jQuery 1.9 but you're using 1.11

Comment: Okay, not a fix, but this jsFiddle accurately simulates your issue:  http://jsfiddle.net/Q9ktb/

Comment: I think it's a bug within `remote`.  It makes no sense to have a `valid` class on the element when you also have an error message displayed on that same element.  You can at least use my jsFiddle to report it on the developer's GitHub site.  https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation

Comment: @Sparky : bah! I'll submit the bug when I get home from work. 
Thanks for sticking around and helping me with it :)

Comment: I've never seen this happen before probably because I never use the `valid/error` classes on the `input` elements.  However, like I said, it makes no sense for there to be a `class` mismatch between the element and its error label.  Then to see the issue go away when not using the `remote` method.  Your original question was confusing... I think if you stick to pointing out what I said in these last two comments, the developer will understand quicker.  You can also fork my fiddle into one without `remote` for comparison.